# Type not match? "...is missing the following properties from type..."

Tags: typescript

I want to do 2 things:
1: Dynamically import package with the name
2: Assert the type of the package(I know what will it return)

```js
type Task = [
  Object, 
  Function
];

const getTasks: Promise<Task[]> = async (names: Array<string>) => {
  const pkgs = names.map(name => import(name) as Promise<Task>);
  return Promise.all(pkgs)
}
```

Error output:

```
Type '(names: string[]) => Promise<[Object, Function][]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<[Object, Function][]>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag], finallyts(2739)
index.ts(55, 35): Did you mean to call this expression?
```

Typescript: 3.3.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Did you mean to call this expression?` in the error message is suggesting that a function is in a place where a value is expected. `getTasks` is declared to be a `Promise` but the expression on the right hand side is a function.

There are 2 options depending on what the intention was. Either immediately invoke the function:

```js
const getTasks: Promise<Task[]> = (async (names: Array<string>) => {
    const pkgs = names.map(name => import(name) as Promise<Task>);
    return Promise.all(pkgs)
})(['package-1', 'package-2']);
```

or (like the name `getTasks` suggests) fix the type to reflect that `getTasks` is a function:

```js
const getTasks: (names: Array<String>) => Promise<Task[]> = async (names: Array<string>) => {
    const pkgs = names.map(name => import(name) as Promise<Task>);
    return Promise.all(pkgs)
}
// or
const getTasks = async (names: Array<string>): Promise<Task[]> => {
    const pkgs = names.map(name => import(name) as Promise<Task>);
    return Promise.all(pkgs)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Umm I guess a small typo? You probably meant to write this...

```
const getTasks = async (names: Array<string>): Promise<Task[]> => { ... }
```